# jQuery $.ajax .fail() is not being fired when connect.facebook.com request fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've a request to connect.facebook, When it fails, the .fail method is not being triggered, but I got the error through the console (403).
I can't find the issue, I also read that for older versions .error is not triggered for crossdomain or jsonp requests.

I'm using jQuery version 1.8.x

```
        var ajax = $.ajax({
            url: document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/' + ('BR' == $('#country').val() ? 'pt_BR' : 'es_LA') + '/sdk.js',
            dataType: "script"
        })
        .done(function () {
            init();
            callback();
        })
        .fail(function () {
            //Never called if facebook is blocked because of network settings. Getting 403 error message.
        });
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: read `$.ajax` docs about `script` requests

Comment: @charlietfl this is the closest match that I have: "If script is specified, $.ajax() will execute the JavaScript that is received from the server before passing it on to the success handler as a string." I really need to know if the request failed...

Comment: you use document.location.protocol -> is it https? Cause facebook uses https

Comment: Yes, @FabianLurz that will be improved, legacy code... The main thing is that the fail is not being triggered, and I don´t know why. If i mispell the url, it fails as it should and the .fail method is called. But if facebook is blocked through network settings, the .fail method is not being called. It seems like the request is blocked even before of being triggered...

Comment: Hm strange - can u make a jsfiddle please? I'll try to help you out here but can't find a problem with this code.

Also if you don't want to handle that yourself (the authentication) you can use hello.js: https://adodson.com/hello.js/

Used it and it works perfectly!

Comment: @FabianLurz really appreciated, that's all the code you need, the thing is not the code itself, but why when failing (403, is a valid error code) is not triggering the fail method. I may be missing something related to the $.ajax inner working...